# Программно установить шрифт и размер в консоли

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, какими средствами можно установить шрифт и размер символов в консоли? ОС Windows, компилятор Visual C++, Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Целевую платформу, полагаю, нам следует угадать самим?

Comment: Встроенного в язык по средства по стандарту нету, C++ как наследник C ограничивается выводом в режиме телетайпа.

Comment: @falstaf: наверняка default platform = MSVC под Windows. Хотя есть шанс, что что-нибудь досовское с `<conio.h>`. :)

Comment: @falstaf, большинство новичков даже и не подозревает, что помимо виндов есть другие платформы.

Comment: Сам-то я с виндой не дружу, но гугл похоже отсылает [вот сюда](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bffea84-e5a0-4fde-bd24-53cbcf1e3025/set-font-text-in-console-application?forum=vclanguage).

Comment: Извините, использую MVS2012, ОСка Windows

Comment: А ссылка по гуглу не помогла? Самому проверять их примеры что-то лень.

Comment: на выходных протестирую

Comment: conio.h нормально отрабатывает только в компиляторе от Borland, насколько я знаю

Comment: у меня MVS12